# Creating JSON File from JavaScript when the JSON Keys have special characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to create such a JSON file from a JavaScript Code in the Node Red Function Node. The goal is to generate the JSON File as follows

```
[
   {
      "H-Nr.":"1",
      "Pos.-Nr.":"1"
   },
   {
      "H-Nr.":"1",
      "Pos.-Nr.":"1"
   },
   {
      "H-Nr.":"1",
      "Pos.-Nr.":"1"
   }
]
```

As the keys contain some special characters like "-" which are not allowed to be a javaScript valid variable, I am not sure how to create a JSON File.

Comment: Both `.` and `-` are valid object property name characters in JS objects and JSON. Are you getting an error when you try to parse this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var obj = {};
obj['H-Nr.'] = '1';
obj['Pos.-Nr'] = '1';

var arr = [obj];

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

You can assign property names as `obj['property-name']` instead of `obj.propertyName`.

Comment: That helps. I still am not sure as to how can I insert the new-line between each property?

Answer (score -2):

I would build the JSON as a string first with JavaScript, then would simply use JSON.parse(string) and store it in some variable.

Comment: That would do the opposite to what the question is asking for.

Comment: Not sure what was I thinking :D, thanks for the correction!